# Is WebRTC sufficient for peer to peer video calling

Tags: webrtc, videocall

I'm building an application with peer-to-peer video calling. So far, I only know WebRTC. Is this sufficient for p2p video calling across the globe if I just have simplest Turn server(s)? By sufficient I mean it is as smooth as a normal video calling services like Google Meet or Zoom. If no, what else should I do to ensure smooth video calling?

Answer (score 1):

For P2P calls with a few participants, WebRTC should absolutely be sufficient. WebRTC has evolved so much in the past decade that it's not unreasonable to estimate that most video applications that are not Zoom are built on it.

There are lots of tutorials about building WebRTC apps from scratch (here's one on [DEV](https://dev.to/michaelneu/i-webrtc-you-building-a-video-chat-in-javascript-2j38), and I appreciate everything [Karl Stolley](https://dev.to/stolleydotdev/i-m-writing-a-book-about-webrtc-for-pragmatic-programmers-1ij5) writes).

The only question is if you *need* to build the WebRTC logic from scratch. [Jitsi](https://jitsi.org/about/) is a good open-source library. There are other solutions with free tiers like [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/webrtc), [Agora](https://www.agora.io/), or [Daily](https://www.daily.co/) (full disclosure, where I work).

Good luck!